Backtesting in python continue build or buy available software
I started building a backtesting application in Python to backtest and optimize trading strategies, but I've paused to assess whether to continue development or purchase software to speed up further progress.
My considerations include processing speed & data, cost & time to implement, and the time to use my software for trading.
I would like advice and opinions on whether it makes sense to migrate my testing to a platform or to continue building, buying data, and scaling speed by setting up infrastructure in the cloud.
Processing speed: My initial speed tests suggest that software (e.g., TradeStation) processes much faster, as expected. I'm using threading/parallel processing and algorithms to increase speed, but I think I may need to configure cloud computing infrastructure to improve speed further (if needed).
Data sources: I want to backtest options strategies, but getting this data isn't as straightforward. For example, TradeStation doesn’t seem to have historical options data for expired contracts, and some data sources aren’t "real" but calculated using models (e.g., Black-Scholes). Some brokers offer options data, some offer backtesting, but few offer both.
Exporting results of backtests: I don’t want this to limit scaling backtesting. Local Python code is only limited by my GPUs, but external software may not allow data downloads or may impose restrictions.
Other considerations

Loss of customizability — Will I lose the ability to customize aspects that might affect results, like changing optimization algorithms (genetic, vector, grid, etc.)?
Other advantages — There may be additional benefits like security, updates, and more.
Cost/Time — To obtain reliable options data, I might need to subscribe to a service. Exporting options data could be more expensive than running tests on their platform.

Possibilities
QuantConnect offers historical options data for expired contracts, an API, and Python compatibility. It advertises "unlimited backtests," but users can run into log limits related to saving results.
TradingView is customizable but uses Pine Script, not Python. It has an API but no options data—though importing options data from other platforms might be possible.
Continuing development will require setting up the right dev ops environment and cloud computing to increase speed. I will also need to buy and integrate reliable options data.
I summarized what I believe the pros and cons are of the different approaches, as well a what I think about each approach in the table below.



Options
Pro
Cons
Between lines




QuantConnect
Speed, equity, historical options data, API, uses Python
"Unlimited backtests" may be limited by log limits
Fastest but potentially the most expensive to scale.


TradingView
Equity data, possible to import options data, unlimited backtesting
Uses Pine Script (not Python), no historical options data
Workarounds needed to import/export options data and backtest results


Continue development
Unlimited backtesting, more economic
Must set up cloud infrastructure and software
Slowest, with potential unknown roadblocks beyond other solutions



Questions

Should I prioritize building backtesting infrastructure in the cloud or migrate to an existing platform like QuantConnect or TradingView or another provider?
How significant are the log limits or restrictions on downloading data from platforms like QuantConnect or TradingView for large-scale backtesting?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

R language has extensive finance libraries with backtesting ,performance measurement and attribution and things that take months to build in python that are ready to go and run fast in seconds, I know this is not what people want to hear but R is the language of professional quants. Python is a swiss army knife a jack of all trades for creating things from scratch, but R is for specific professions because it  is for vector mathematics and functional programming it is the mathematical and statistical language of science and finance. There is a lot in python, but not for specific things, ready built, like extreme value theory, and all the methods of active trading from Grinold and Kahn, and Carl Bacon's performance measurement book,Quantmod in R downloads current and future options strikes and expiries data free, as well as FRED economic data, and share prices.You can buy historical option data, from a number of sources, but ORATS has an extensive options backtester and historical prices going back to 2007, it is a subscripton service POA depending on requirements,it is not related to R in anyway. I have been trading options since 2007 and tried dozens of software as a service options tools and they are not good or realistic, they find marvelous anomalies which are not repeatable trades and they are not in real time. The main workhorses in R are Rmetrics libraries PerformanceAnalytics libraries, Quantstrat, and blotter, and Rquantlib, and they are very comprehensive and there is at least a dozen more I have not tried. They have from traditional markowitz portfolios to Kelly criterion, sharp ratios, American and European options, unfortunately the Heston Nandi volatility pricing model for options has been discontinued, but I rewrote the code from git hub, I find tree models better, so I do not use it. I have a parallel library of python open source code and it is not very robust or functional or as useful for real trading. In R there is built in libraries for event studies and metrics, Risk management , plus a vast array of finance related things ready to go, no programming required just code commands. There is not a lot of secrets to trading options, as arbitrage is limited to few types the main type is volatility arbitrage also known as statistical arbitrage, it is persistent and consistent and provides steady returns. Also if you use tastytrade as a broker they released a good free options trading backtester with their platform to anyone who signs up, you can use their data without even trading or depositing any money, they are simply a very good but not the cheapest option broker, and you can trades shares, and futures with them also, and I believe crypto for what thats worth. This is not what people want to hear in python universe but it saves reinventing the wheel, if you can program python, then R is a bit more like C syntax, but still clean and simple, but it has some unique tricks for vectors and arrays and graphics.

Incidentally I am not a high frequency trader, and not interested in computers doing my trades, I trade like a pit trader and use quant tools, as you need hundreds of thousands probably millions to make money with high frequency trading, the two types of trading are not related. High frequency trading algorithms have to be frequently reinvented because there is such enormous competition

To continue.........it takes endless programming hours just to stay afloat, where as just being a retail trader who knows the path less traveled of unorthodox finance such as kelly criterion and volatility pumping and statistical arbitrage has been a breadwinner since the opening of the Chicago options exchange in 1972, technical. high frequency, anamolies all change by minute monthly or daily and it is a constant struggle to profit,

To continue further..........most are fooled by the mystique of such hedge funds as renaissance medallion, they made and continue to make the bulk of there returns out of a Hidden Markov Model high frequency trading prediction model to scalp before the market makers settle, it is not a realistic dream for an individual retail investor it requires huge servers and collocation to dark pools in which trades are made, this alone costs hundreds of millions of dollars in fees. And the algorithm has to be constantly modified every day or even more frequently.

I suggest if you can pull that programming mess off, try and get a job as a programmer for a hedge fund or investment bank, you will really make money then, as it is you are wasting thousands of hours in which you could be making money by just learning to trade. Instead of looking for the lost city of El Dorado, and its gold paved streets.

crypto is completely random, I refer you to tulip bulb mania in Holland in the 1600s , one day people are not going to play the game anymore, although, it is unbelievable how many gormless gullible people there really is. It is a giant ponzi scheme.

I, with my team, have written Python-based algorithmic trading framework and infrastructure at TradingStrategy.ai for decentralised finance protocols, so let me share my thoughts.
Primarily:

For common use cases, like options trading on established markets, you should find existing Python libraries available, even if not full backtesting frameworks
You can customise these for your needs
Unless you are an expert Python developer, developing your framework is a good learning experience, but it is a large time sink

Time to market

If you can get started with TradingView, TradeStation, MetaTrader or other similar software you should go for it
Better to have zero to one moment and then later figure out how to do it properly

On the performance of Python code:

For data crunching, Python uses native libraries like NumPy and Polars and speed is not an issue, unless you do high-frequency trading
For example, we rent a heavy Google Cloud server for backtesting, running Datalore for Python notebooks, with 64 CPUs, where we pay by the hour and we have a script to automatically turn the server off
Most backtesting is in optimization/grid search and these tasks are trivial to parallerise
Our approach is hybrid: we build our indicator data using vectorised calculations with Pandas, but the trade decision loop is still event driven as this way we can take the unmodified backtest code and put it to the live trade execution

On data sources for options trading:

Options trading is more niche, so datasets are naturally more scarce
Someone collects this data, but you might need to pay for it
Usually more sophisticated datasets and larger downloads are behind "professional" or "enterprise plan"
That's why I love cryptocurrency markets, as all data is public and free
I am not an expert on options trading on traditional finance, so I cannot give you any pointers on data sources for your specific needs

On customizability:

We are using our own datasets, trade order types, which are not compatible with any existing services like TradingView
Because DeFi data is somewhat special, we had to write our own backtester
We can still utilise existing Python libraries like pandas_ta and talib
Even if you get backtester with a ready made tool, you need to think the live trade execution (unless you plan to do it by hand)

On devops

For live trading, you are going to need some kind of devops solutions any case
Most issues are related failing third party APIs and how to handle and recover these situations
This may mean servers, alerts, etc. and people - people are the most important one here
We are "logging" from the live execution to Discord channels - one per strategy, but Telegram group chats and bots are also popular for alerts and status updates
Servers are cheap, it is mostly that you might need a sysadmin knowledge with any Python solution
However this can come afer "1.0" when you have something in place, even if it is put together with a duct tape


Thanks Mikko. Using some libaries mentioned above, I have than my planned testing and improving my software to ensure it works across multiple strategies and integrating the API, what are some development tasks or features that you found unexpectedly time-consuming or more complex than initially expected?
Were there any particular parts of your trading framework (e.g., data handling, real-time monitoring, order execution) that you thought would be straightforward but turned out to require significantly more work?

Thanks Mikko. Ive developed min software to backtest, optimize & parallelize strategy & trade with API. I plan to test improve software to work w/ multiple strategies & integrate with trading API.  what are some development tasks I should consider? or features that you found unexpectedly time-consuming or more complex than initially expected? Were there any particular parts of your trading framework (e.g., data handling, real-time monitoring, order execution) that you thought would be straightforward but turned out to require significantly more work?

@MMsmithH it's too many questions to answer in comments, but if you are patient I can write a blog post later

Sounds good, please let me know when you do!

I wrote my first backtester in Python. After this I moved to C# that I knew already.
About your question, remember that using someone's frameworks you are limiting yourself to someone's solution.
If you want to scale your backtester or experiment with different solutions, I suggest to have your own.

I have had a similar challenge a few times and even been starting to write a backtester in R a few years ago. Abandoned the project because, as mentioned earlier, its only really worthwhile if building a trading platform or if you need to be really specific for what you are doing. If you need to run a few ideas there is enough work in thinking hard about bias, order execution etc.
Regarding your first question: I recently looked at the market to test a quick options on futures hedging strategy and QuantConnect looked like a decent package to me. Depending on the markets you need, you might find that many markets offer data (for a fee). CME has an offering, including full options and futures data, called DataMine. So an important consideration might be if the platform you identify allows good data import features.
On the second question: The log limits are important in two cases. First if you are not yet experienced enough with the platform and need to log logs of debug during design/build - rather then using the Jupyter notebook for that. Second, when you run live strategies you want to know what is happening. QuantConnect has plans that should give you want you needs if restricting the critical logs (orders are tracked separately) and you can always send notifications to a an other service.
